# How to use Microsoft Graph chart in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba

I've been pulling my hair out for almost a week now trying to figure out how to insert a line graph into a form in Access 2013 to plot temperature vs time.  Just a simple x/y line graph, with time on the bottom and temp as the y axis.  I cannot for the life of me find any sort of introductory "how to use ms graph" help file, forum, or tutorial.  I'm not at all familiar with using SQL to write my own queries, and everything that access has generated for me might as well be complete nonsense.  None of it looks anything like a line chart, and looking through the code that it made, I can't figure out how to modify it to suit my needs.  Is there anyone who can explain how to format a Microsoft Graph to display data from a table where the first column is a DateTime and the second is an integer, so that I'm looking at plot of temperature over time?  It blows my mind that a database program should have such a user-unfriendly approach to analyzing data visually.
Also, because I've seen this in other forums, I'm trying to avoid any interaction with excel.  The end goal here is to make a form that will run using MS Access runtime to analyze information gathered from a PLC, to provide a neat little visualization for the machine's operators.  I just can't believe that I managed to get the form to call the right DLLs to pull data from a PLC, but Access's built-in chart is kicking my butt!

Comment: A little late but.. If you're not making use of queries, why are you using Access and why can you not use Excel? Excel is intended for data gathering and visualization, while Access is more for organization, categorization, etc...it's a database application, and it's generally disagreeable to throw data straight into it.

Comment: @ZX9 I strongly disagree. Excel does not have nearly the power Access does when it comes to validation and user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot chart reporting was removed in Access 2013 it was in 2010 but it seems that microsoft seem to be decapricating access in favour of excell which is getting most attention.
The nearest you can do is create a data connection to access then do the chart in excel

http://blogs.office.com/2013/01/22/visualize-your-access-2013-web-app-data-in-excel/

A bit pants I know, sorry